# How to adjust sizing of a tilemap in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make my first 2D game for a game jam, and I am planning to use a tilemap. As practice I have imported a tileset sheet and sliced it into 16x16 pixels per unit, since that is what the assets are based on. It slices up fine and looks good in playmode, but I am confused about how to adjust the sizing of the scene. For instance, if I wanted a more "zoomed out" look where more of the screen is available to view by the player, is that something I can adjust in Unity?

Comment: For a more zoomed out look, you would adjust the camera. Since this is 2D you are probably using an orthographic camera, thus you would need to adjust the `orthographicSize` property of the camera.